# Behavior of append when appending item to a max size slice

Tags: go, slice

I'm confused about the behavior when appending to a slice which already has the max possible size.

As far as my understanding goes a slice can either have a max size of int32 or int64 depending on your system.

When executing `test := make([]struct{},math.MaxInt64+1)` I get the error `len argument too large in make([]struct {})` which is within my expectations.
But when doing something like:

```
test := make([]struct{},math.MaxInt64)
for i:=0;i<100 ; i++ {
    test = append(test, struct{}{})
}
fmt.Println(len(test))
```

I expect the program to panic but surprisingly the code runs with out any problems and `len` returns an overflowed value with `-9223372036854775709`.

Could someone maybe elaborate the behavior?

(I'm using go1.11.2 linux/amd64)

Comment: Why does this matter? A max-size slice of `struct{}` is useless, and a max-size slice of anything else will likely exceed available memory.

Comment: I'm writing an adapter for a Linear Programming c-library. This library has multiple functions which are taking arrays of ints with a possible sizeof struct_t. I used an empty struct because I ran out of memory, doesn't mean that the server/computer used for solving math problems will.

Comment: The address space is determined by the same factor (32 or 64 bit architecture) as the maximum slice length. If your slice was of `byte`, you could theoretically store a max size slice on a machine with maximum memory for its architecture, but that would leave zero space for OS, Go runtime, or the rest of your program. So... yes, the server/computer running it will indeed run out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec says about [length and capacity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity) of any slice:

> At any time the following relationship holds:
>
> ```
> 0 <= len(s) <= cap(s)
> ```

This is clearly violated, as the length becomes negative, and thus less than 0. So this is a bug, already reported it and progress can be tracked here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29190

Ian Lance Taylor confirms this is a bug and not how it should work. The proper behavior would be a panic saying `growslice: cap out of range`, which should originate from [`slice.go / growslice()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go) function (`growslice()` is called from `append()`).

If we slightly modify your example to this:

```
s := make([]struct{}, math.MaxInt32-2)
fmt.Println(len(s), cap(s))
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    s = append(s, struct{}{})
    fmt.Println(len(s), cap(s))
}
```

And run it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AUKUBmQld_e):

```
2147483645 2147483645
2147483646 2147483646
2147483647 2147483647
-2147483648 2147483647
-2147483647 2147483647
-2147483646 2147483647
```

As we can see, the capacity stops growing once it reaches `MaxInt32` on 32-bit architectures, and `MaxInt64` on 64-bit architectures.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and posting the issue on github! Have a great day :)

Comment: I don't know if its relevant (safety issues or alike) but when executing your sniped with a non empty struct, like https://play.golang.org/p/IAOFh2ZOrfh , on my local machine with 'GOARCH=386 go run test.go' I get a segmentation violation

Comment: @Nordiii It is related to this issue (length becomes negative). Once the bug is fixed, the code will not get that far, and will properly stop with a runtime panic (`rowslice: cap out of range`).